# Implement a generic interface missing new constraint

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Consider the following interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    M Bar<M>();
}
```

Trying to implement that with

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    public M Bar<M>()
    {
        return new M();
    }
}
```

does not work, the compiler complains the `M` is missing a `new()` constraint.

When I add the constraint as in

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    public M Bar<M>() where M : new()
    {
        return new M();
    }
}
```

this still does not do the trick, as the constraints of `Foo.Bar` do not match the constraints of the interface method now (and I'm not able to change that).

The [documentation for the compiler error CS0425](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/132x8zxh.aspx) says

> To avoid this error, make sure the where clause is identical in both
>   declarations, or implement the interface explicitly.

If "implementing the interface explicitly" is the solution: How do I do it?

Comment: Is this because you need to return a new one or you need to return something when there is nothing else to return? Would `default(M)` be good enough? It returns the default value for a given generic type, for references this is `null`. Otherwise you will need either expression trees or reflection to create your instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can't change the interface definition, you'll have to avoid using `new M();` - use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
class Foo : IFoo
{
    public M Bar<M>()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<M>();
    }
}
```

Of course, you may now run into a runtime error if there's no parameterless constructor for `M`, but that's unavoidable (again, because we can't change the generic constraints).

---

Re: documentation:

> implement the interface explicitly.

I *think* that what they're trying to get at here is "if you've got a base class method that has one set of generic constraints and you want to implement an interface that has a different set of constraints for a method with the same name, explicit implementation is one way out of that bind".

Comment: Thank you for interpreting the documentation: You're probably right. I was in the mode of thinking "the documentation explains what I've done wrong and shows a way out of the plight", which led me on a wrong path.

Answer (score 6):

Implementing the interface explicitly is *not* the solution. The compiler is simply telling you that if you need a generic method `Bar` with that constraint, then implement the interface explicitly so *both* versions of `Bar` can coexist, but that is, obviously, not the solution your are lookig for.

The only solutions are:

1. Implement the generic type constraint in the interface.
2. Instantiate the new `M` via reflection: `Activator.CreateInstance` and pay the price of losing type safety at compile time; nothing enforces `M` to have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Nothing is enforcing that `M` is even a type that you can instantiate, could be an interface.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Well yes, any non instantiable type is lacking a usable parameterless constructor. I fail to see the difference you are trying to make.

Comment: No difference, just pointing out that no parameterless constructor is the least of the issues really - an observation more than anything. Just reminds me why I tend not to make or use interfaces like this.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth ah ok, understood.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate explicit interface implementation by right clicking interface in class which should implement it and selecting "implement explicitly". Methods names should be pereceded with interface's name.